# Git in same directory for Mac and Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, macos

Yesterday I started using Git to version control documents I'm working on. I use two systems, a Windows 10 desktop, and a MacBook Air. I save the documents to a directory on the internet, think Dropbox.

I configured Git to use the internet directory for Windows 10. Is it *also* possible to use this same directory for Git on my Mac? Or do I instruct my Git on the Mac to use a different directory on the Mac?

Git Mac: 2.15.1 (No manual entry for gitwork-tree)
Git Windows 10: 2.16.2.windows.1

Comment: Are you going to be using the same repo (same directory) from multiple computers?

Answer (score 2):

Every version control system maintains the directory name of the local folder the same name as the repository (Source Folder). Then if you clone your project from git repository ( `git clone https://github.com/myaccount/my-project` ) the diretory name in any Operating System will be the same of the repository "my-project".